# Gmap.Net alternative in c++ under linux

Tags: c#, c++, linux, google-maps

I have written  an application that uses Gmap.NET for displaying Google map and place some markers on Geo-coordinates and of course the application is written in C# under windows .Now what i want is to rewrite this application in C++ under Linux any one could tell what is the alternative for Gmap.NET in this case.

i want this alternative library to be able to do

1.Display Google map on a GTKmm2.4 Widget (for some reason regarding the development of the application ).

2.To be able to place markers on the map based on the Geo-Location aka Latitude and longitude Coordinates .

Answer (score 0):

p.s. it's possible to use GMap.NET on linux using mono

Comment: i know but i'm rewriting  the whole application using c++ and i want keep it this way